# Objects are not valid as a react child (found : TypeError : filepath.includes is not a function)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, react-native-fetch-blob

I ran into this problem when I tried using `react-native-fetch-blob` to  upload photos in firebase storage! 
This is the code for uploading the file.

```js
uploadImage = (uri, imageName, mime = 'image/jpg') => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const uploadUri = uri
    let uploadBlob = null
    const imageRef = firebase.storage().ref('posts').child(imageName)
    fs.readFile(uploadUri, 'base64')
      .then((data) => {
        return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` })
      })
      .then((blob) => {
        uploadBlob = blob
        return imageRef.put(blob, { contentType: mime })
      })
      .then(() => {
        uploadBlob.close()
        return imageRef.getDownloadURL()
      })
      .then((url) => {
        resolve(url)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        reject(error)
      })
  })
}
```

This is the code which calls the function uploadImage:

```js
this.uploadImage(this.state.avatarUri.uri, userId).then((imageURL) => {
  saveDatabase(userId, imageURL)
}).catch((error) => {
  this.setState({
    error,
    isLoading: false
  })
})
```

The avatarUri is set from the imagepicker library as follows:

```js
openCamera = () => {

  ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary({}, (response) => {
    if (response.didCancel) {

    } else if (response.error) {
      this.state.imageError = response.error
      console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', this.state.imageError);
    } else if (response.customButton) {
      console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
    } else {
      this.setState({
        avatarUri: {
          uri: response.uri
        },
        imgPath: response.imgPath,
        error: ''
      });
    }
  });

}
```

The error screenshot is here:

[image: Error encountered]

**EDIT**
Render Function is as following:

```
        this.state.isLoading ? 
            <Spinner style={{flex:1, alignSelf: 'center'}} color='blue' />
        :
        <Container>
        <Content style={{margin:20}}>

            <Item>
                <Icon type="FontAwesome" active name='user' style={{ color :'#c5aa6a'}} />
                <Input 
                    placeholder='Email' 
                    onChangeText= { (text)=> { this.setEmailText(text) } } 
                    value={this.state.email}/>
            </Item>

            <Item>
                <Icon type="FontAwesome" active name='key' style={{ color :'#c5aa6a'}} />
                <Input 
                    secureTextEntry 
                    placeholder='Password'
                    onChangeText= { (text)=> { this.setPasswordText(text) } } 
                    value={this.state.password}
                    />
            </Item>

            <Item>
                <Icon type="FontAwesome" active name='key' style={{ color :'#c5aa6a'}} />
                <Input 
                    secureTextEntry 
                    placeholder='Confirm Password'
                    onChangeText= { (text)=> { this.setRePasswordText(text) } } 
                    value={this.state.re_password}
                    />
            </Item>

            <Button bordered success  style={{ justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 20}} onPress = { ()=> this.verifyCredentials() } >
                <Text style={{color:'#c5aa6a'}}>Sign Up</Text>
            </Button>

            {
                !this.state.avatarUri ?
                <Icon type="FontAwesome" active name='user-circle' style={styles.photoPicker} onPress= { ()=> this.openCamera() } /> :
                <Image style={styles.avatarPicked}  source= {  this.state.avatarUri }  />

            }

            { 
                this.state.error ? 
                    <Text style= {{ color: '#ff0000', alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 30}}>    {this.state.error}  </Text>
                    :
                    null
            }

        </Content>

        <Button transparent onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('login')} style={styles.buttonStyle} >
            <Text style={{color:'#c5aa6a'}}>I already have an account</Text>
        </Button>

        </Container>
```

Comment: I think no issue with the function's, but with your render function. Check your render function, and see where you are trying to render something from your state.

Comment: Updated my render function!